# login user by user id in JWT Auth in laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I know , that exists way how to login users by theirs ids:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id)
```

but how to do it in JWT Auth? I tried something like this:

```
JWTAuth::loginUsingId($user_id)
```

but it returns me error: Method loginUsingId does not exist!

So, how to login user by their user_id in jwt auth?

Comment: It should be `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be aware that JWT Auth does not have the same behaviour as a classic session login system. Apart from that, in JWTAuth, you can login a user from a `User` object:

```
// grab some user
$user = User::first();

$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

So if you only have access to id:

```
$user = User::find($id);
JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

> Source: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens